# How to clear jasny input mask before using in Laravel validator?

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, jasny-bootstrap

I have a form field to get mobile number of users:

```
<input class="form-control" name="mobile" data-mask="0999 999 9999" type="text" id="mobile" />
```

I used [jasny input mask](http://www.jasny.net/bootstrap/javascript/#inputmask) to guide users for entering data but I need to save mobile number in format **999999999** into database (Without 0 and spaces).

As I use ajax to send data to server by serialize() function, I don't want to use client side script to change entered value (I have many such form fields) unless by changing or adding a function or method to jasny input mask to use on all such fields!

I get the entered value server-side and I want to assign it to a model attribute in Laravel 5 so in user model I declared an accessor and a mutator to set and get mobile number:

```
public function setMobileAttribute($value){
    $value = substr(str_replace(" ","",$value),1);
    $this->attributes['mobile'] = $value;
}
```

and

```
public function getMobileAttribute($value){
    return '0'.substr($value,0,3).' '.substr($value,3,3).' '.substr($value,6,4);
}
```

It works nice but when I want to use Laravel validation to indicate it's a unique field, it doesn't work.
Peace of code is like:

```
class UserController extends Controller {

    protected $rules = ['mobile' => 'required|unique:users'];
    public function store(Request $request){
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $this->rules);
        if ($validator->fails()){
            return response()->json([
                'success' => false,
                'errors' => $validator->getMessageBag()->toArray()
            ]);
        }
        // codes to store user...
    }
}
```

It cause to error:
*SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry*

Comment: I think you are attempting to save a mobile number that already exists in the DB?

Comment: yes, I want to prevent users to do that, so I should validate mobile numbers before save into DB and show profit message if mobile number already exist!

Answer (score 0):

I found a way not perfect but is good.
I add this function to my UserController class:

```
private function sanitize(Request $request){
    $input = $request->all();
    $input['mobile'] = substr(str_replace(" ","",$input['mobile']),1);
    $request->replace($input);
    return $request->all();
}
```

and use Laravel validator like this:

```
$validator = Validator::make($this->sanitize($request), $this->rules);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue so I have solved it, here is my code:

```
$mobile = str_replace(['(', ')', ' ', '-'], ['', '', '', ''], $request->post('mobile'));
$request->merge(array('mobile' => $mobile));

    $request->validate([
        'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
        'password' => ['required', 'max:50', 'min:8'],
        'phone' => ['required', 'unique:users']
    ]);
```